# preg_match gets a number, which doesn't exist in the subject string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_match()`, but can't figure out a problem.

```
$pattern = "/\_image\_([0-9])\.jpg/";
$subject = "/image/2_image_2.jpg";
$Id = preg_match($pattern, $subject);
dd($Id);
```

I'm trying to get the **second 2** (not the first one), but the result is **1**, which doesn't exist in the subject.

I'm new to regex, clueless as to why this happens.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: 1 means 1 match is found, use `$Id = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $mymatches);` -> `$mymatches` will contain the strings matched and captured. BTW, the regex you have does not match the string - https://regex101.com/r/gM7hR1/1. What is the real regex or string you have?

Comment: And - you're trying to match `thumbnail` with `image`... Guess that's a typo?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 means a regex expression found a match in the input string. See [`preg_match` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> `preg_match()` returns `1` if the pattern matches given subject, `0` if it does not, or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

You can use the following code then:

```
$pattern = '/_image_([0-9])\.jpg/';
$subject = "/image/2_image_2.jpg";
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches))
    echo $matches[1];
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/QcQRhF)

Main points:

- Use single quoted literal to define the regex (it is not a problem as PHP treats unknown escape sequences as `\` and a symbol, but that might not be good for the internals)
- Pass the 3rd argument `$matches` to the `preg_match` so as to be able to access the matched/captured values
- Check if there is a match before accessing the captured value
- Group 1 (captured value) can be accessed via `$matches[1]`.